# Using a rotational latch to restrain an object under a horizontal force

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

So hypothetically, I'd like a to build a latching system to prevent a steel block experiencing a horizontal force from moving  until another upwards force releases a latch, at which point it would allowed to move. Not shown, downward force is applied to the latch by a spring.

So obviously, this design will not work because releasing the latch would require pushing the steel block in the opposite direction of the force, but there is another object in the way preventing that motion.

Perhaps the latch could flex? But that does not seem durable given a large horizontal force?

#### Is there a *simple* soltuion to allow this basic design to work as intended without requiring the moving object to move counter to the resisted horizontal force when the latch is released?

I am not a professional mechanical engineer, so I apologize if I have not worded this in an easily understandable way; please feel free to suggest edits to make things more clear.

Comment: This looks like a trigger mechanism...

Comment: @SolarMike ????

Comment: Have a look at this resource: Alexander Slocum's wonderful guide to making stuff. Page 19 of this pdf shows you how to make a trigger mechanisms. https://web.mit.edu/2.75/fundamentals/FUNdaMENTALs%20Book%20pdf/FUNdaMENTALs%20Topic%204.PDF

Comment: @DDuck thank you for this wonderful resource!